# Area and setting equations are set equal to each other

Tags: integration, area

Is the area between the points of intersection equal to the area under the graph of the equation you get when you set the equations equal to each other?

To make it easier to understand my question, [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dc347zvjkf) shows three functions, where f(x) and g(x) are the original functions, and h(x) is the equation you get when you set them equal to each other and solve. Is the area between the points of intersection of f(x) and g(x) equal to the area over the graph of h(x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your first case you have $$\int_{-2}^23+2x-x^2-(2x-1)dx=\frac{32}{3}$$
and we get $$\int_{-2}^2 -(x^2-4)dx=\frac{32}{3}$$ this they have equal areas

Comment: thanks for your help!